# Extending the range of a Remote Keyless Entry RKE key fob

Tags: amplifier, rf

If it possible to amplify the RF emitted from my key fob to dramatically increase it's range when attempting to remote start my car?  My wife is a nurse and leaves the hospital late at night.  She'd like to remote start her car (especially in the winter) to minimize the amount of time she spends in the parking lot.

Any ideas?

Even if it's something she has to carry in her purse that's OK.  Other people have RKE systems that operate over a longer distance and they can start their car OK, but my wife's is not powerful enough.  Tried changing the battery, but that didn't help.

Comment: Info on car model or keyfob fcc id would help. If it's a keyless start, those have a range of ones of feet and are similar to rfid. If it's a remote starter keyfob, it might just need a better antenna, but we need something to base it off of.

Comment: Like Passerby said, we need frequency band information etc. in order to answer this one properly.

Comment: Possible yes. Easy no. The first approach is install an big antenna on receiver or transmitter (or both).

Answer (score 0):

Have her put the tip of the key in her open mouth, aimed at the car, with the  key's metal touching a front tooth.  Absolutely not kidding.  Can't pretend to understand the theory, but maybe a waves guru can explain.  I think its effective line-of-sight.

Comment: [This](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5167) is an interesting read. But the best technical explanation is yet to be found ;)

Comment: This has been discussed before :- [Why does holding my car's RF remote to my head extend its range?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/21671/2234)

Answer (score -3):

Have her try pointing the key on the key fob directly towards the ca while trying to ensure a clear line of sight between her key fob and the car. 
A key fob is a small radio transmitter and these might help get the signal through.

Comment: That's _not_ what the OP asked for.